# How to cast type to it's generic base type

Tags: c#, generics

I have code structure:

`SpecificType.cs`

```
public class SpecificType : TypeBase<SpecificT, SpecificV>
    where T : ITBase
    where V : IVBase
{ ... }
```

`SpecificT.cs`

```
public class SpecificT : ITBase { ... }
```

`SpecificV.cs`

```
public class SpecificV : IVBase { ... }
```

`TypeBase.cs`

```
public class TypeBase<T, V> : IBase<T, V>
    where T : ITBase
    where V : IVBase
{ ... }
```

`IBase.cs`

```
public interface IBase<T, V>
    where T : ITBase
    where V : IVBase
{ ... }
```

All I want to do is cast my `SpecificType` to it's most abstract type - `IBase<T,V>`:

```
SpecificType specTypeObject = new SpecificType();
IBase<ITBase, IVBase> typeObject = (IBase<ITBase, IVBase>)specTypeObject;
```

All I receive is `InvalidCastException`. Is this even possible I want to achieve?

Comment: Why do you need to do explicit casting since you go down to the base class? How do you use type attributes in implementation? As only in input locations or output locations?

Comment: [MSDN: Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Which .NET version do you use?

Comment: @neo - unfortunately, .NET Core for Windows 10. Does it change anything? :P

Comment: If it's before .NET 4.0, it can change.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is type safety. Let's say we have **Fruit** class and 2 other classes deriving from it **Apple** and **Cocunut**. The following example is from **C# 5.0 Unleashed** book.

```
Apple[] apples = new Apple[] { apple1, apple2, apple3 };

// Because of array type covariance we can write the following.
Fruit[] fruits = apples;

// We're putting a Coconut, which is a Fruit, in a Fruit array. This is   fine.
fruits[2] = new Coconut();
// An element of an Apple[] should be an Apple, right?
apples[2].Peel();
```

As the example shows, type safety is broken when letting type argument to be used for input. Since Coconut is a Fruit, we were able to input it into Apple array because we cast down the Apple array to Fruit array. When using Fruit array reference, we were able to insert Coconut among the Apples. When we call Peel method on the coconut, we get an error since coconut has no Peel method. This breaks type safety. To avoid this, type parameters' use must be indicated as input or output by saying **out T** or **in T**. If you define as **out T**, then you can use T only as return value from methods. If you define as **in T**, then you can only use T in input locations. This way type safety is established. If you need to use T for both input and output, then you can't do the cast you want since it breaks type safety.

Answer (score 3):

```
SpecificType specTypeObject = new SpecificType();
IBase<ITBase, IVBase> typeObject = (IBase<ITBase, IVBase>)specTypeObject;
```

You can't do this cast because `SpecificType` is not of type `IBase<ITBase, IVBase>`. `SpecificType` actually has a base type of `IBase<SpecificT, SpecificV`, so the following works:

```
SpecificType specTypeObject = new SpecificType();       
IBase<SpecificT, SpecificV> typeObject = (IBase<SpecificT, SpecificV>)specTypeObject;
```

---

You could add covariance specifiers to get it to work:

```
public interface IBase<out T, out V>
    where T : ITBase
    where V : IVBase
    {}

var specTypeObject = new SpecificType();
var typeObject = (IBase<ITBase, IVBase>)specTypeObject;
```

Now this works. This might prevent certain operations on your `IBase` interface though, for instance a method like `void Add(T t)` would not be allowed within `IBase`.

Also, just for the sake of completeness, make note that you can't apply covariance or contravariance to generic classes, only interfaces and delegates. So the following does not work: `public class TypeBase<out T, out V> : IBase<T, V>`

Comment: Thanks for answer. Unfortunately, one of my operations is `void Insert(T type)` which, as you said, isn't possible.

Comment: Yeah, in that case, the least specific type you can cast to (aside from object) is `IBase<SpecificT, SpecificV>`.

Comment: Yup, guys explained me that :) As I wrote under T McKeown answer, I solved problem removing generic interface.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but you'd have to traverse up the type's hierarchy stack to determine or build code that performs casting checks to determine what you're after.

Comment: Can you explain why I have to use reflection? I think inheritance hierarchy is easy to expand for compiler.

Comment: @Fk2 read up on co- and contravariance in C#.  Crucially, `List<Animal>` is not a base type of `List<Tiger>`.  You *could* do what you want if you can declare the type parameters of `IBase` as covariant, but you will not be able to declare them as such if they are ever used in an "input" position.

Comment: I mispoke, you'd have to use the `Type` and move up it's declaration stack, my answer points out that you can code something that could test the instance for certain types that should determine the base class easily.

Comment: @phoog - your answer leaded me to understaing of a problem.

Comment: @Fka I'm happy I was able to help.  This series by Eric Lippert helped me a lot: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one/  (His current blog is at http://www.ericlippert.com).  You might also want to check out his work on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A88656+covariance

Comment: I solved problem refactoring `IBase<T, V>` to `IBase` which operates on basic types. Then, in my `TypeBase<T, V>` I just use cast operator to cast on `SpecificT` or `SpecificV` type and finally `SpecificType<T,V>` doesn't even know anything changed.